# ffmpeg, how to concat two streams, one with and one without audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have one clip filmed at 240 FPS.  I want to slow it down 8x and concat the slow motion version of it to the fast version.  The fast version has audio but the slow does not.  When I open the finished movie using totem in Ubuntu I get no sound.  However, the sound appears to be correct when I use VLC.  I think this is an issue with the sound not being the same length as the final movie.  I think I somehow need to pad the sound to the length of the final movie.  Anyone know how to pad the audio or a better way to do this?

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -i GX010071_1.MP4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=8*PTS[s];[0:v]framerate=30[f]; [f] [s] concat=n=2 [c]" -map '[c]' -map 0:a -c:v hevc_nvenc SLOW.MP4
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I just needed to combine the apad filter with the shortest option.  The following command works.

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -i GX010071_1.MP4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=8*PTS[s];[0:v]framerate=30[f]; [f] [s] concat=n=2 [c]" -map '[c]' -map 0:a -af apad -c:v hevc_nvenc -shortest SLOW.MP4
```